# How small can $u$ be in the Pell equation $u^2-k^3 v^2=\pm 1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

Let $k$ be positive integer, not a square and let $u_k,v_k$ be non-trivial
solutions to the Pell equation $u_k^2-k^3 v_k^2=\pm 1$.

> Q1 How small $u_k$ can be infinitely often as function $k$?

This gives rise to the good abc triple $(u_k^2,-k^3 v_k^2,\mp 1)$
so abc implies $u_k$ can't be too small, it can't be $\log(u_k)=C\log(k)$.

$k/\log(u_k)$ appears to diverge.

$\log^2(k^3) / \log(u_k)$ appears better, with large sporadic peaks.
$\log(k^3)/\log(u_k)$ doesn't appear to go to zero fast and
also have sporadic peaks.

> Q2 for positive constants $C_0, 1 \le C < 2$ do we have $u_k<C_0 \exp(\log^C(k^3))$

Possible approach is to find $\sqrt{k^3}$ with relatively short continued
fraction expansion.

We believe the set of small $u_k$ to be very sparse, so the numerical
evidence might be misleading.

$k$ is on the $x$ axis:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @FedericoPoloni As $k$ varies I am computing $u$ and then plot log(k)/log(u), there is legend at top.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, $k$ is on $x$ axis, sage doesn't label them. I think I am missing some $k$ because $u$ is rather large, will try to make it better.

Comment: The classic paper on abc, by J.Browkin-J.Brzeziński, has applied continued fractions.